# Arch Linux support for ROS

Tags: ros, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am willing to work on adding support for ROS in Arch in my free time. Pls contact me or whom should i contact.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194142/arch-linux-support-for-ros/) by [neoDEH](https://answers.ros.org/users/20383/neodeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The last section of the [Installation Instructions for Indigo in Arch Linux](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Arch) page -- [Community](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Arch#Community) -- says this:

> If you would like to contribute to packaging ROS on Arch, check [arch-ros-stacks](https://github.com/bchretien/arch-ros-stacks) on GitHub (as explained in [#1.2](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Arch#Adding_New_AUR_Packages)), or even [https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talk:Ros].

The [README.md](https://github.com/bchretien/arch-ros-stacks/blob/master/README.md) on the linked [Github repository](https://github.com/bchretien/arch-ros-stacks) has a [How to contribute](https://github.com/bchretien/arch-ros-stacks#how-to-contribute) section:

> If you want to contribute, simply fork this repository, create or update some packages, and make a pull request afterwards.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [neoDEH](https://answers.ros.org/users/20383/neodeh/) on 2014-10-06**:
Thanks for the links

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-06**:
Please use the 'add a comment' link under the answer in the future. Adding an answer is really only for adding *answers*. Also, if you find an answer posted by a user to be the *actual* answer to your question, please mark it as such by clicking the checkmark next to it (under the down arrow). Tnx.

**Comment by [neoDEH](https://answers.ros.org/users/20383/neodeh/) on 2014-10-06**:
ok, sorry am new to the site.

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-12-02**:
Indeed, just fork my repo, follow the instructions, and make a pull request. There's a script that takes care of generating/updating the PKGBUILDs, which you can use if you want to add new ROS packages and maintain them for the AUR.